# Debugging SQL in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql, subsonic

```
private void BuildGridView2()
{
    GridView1.DataSource = new Select()
    .From("NewsReleases")
    .Where("RelMonth").IsEqualTo(this.ddlAward.SelectedValue)
    .And("RelYear").IsEqualTo(this.ddlYear.SelectedValue)
    .OrderAsc("RelDate")
    .ExecuteDataSet();

 }
```

The SQL statement above is not working for some reason.
Is there a way to write the output of the staement to to the page to see what is happening?

I tired the following but got an error:

```
Response.Write(
    new Select()
        .From("NewsReleases")
        .Where("RelMonth").IsEqualTo(this.ddlAward.SelectedValue)
        .And("RelYear").IsEqualTo(this.ddlYear.SelectedValue).ToString()
);
```

Comment: Where does your class Select come from?

Comment: @Brett: What error do you get?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799953/asp-net-search-on-multiple-parameters Please re-read the answer ranomore gave you Brett.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Subsonic, but according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521023/debug-a-subsonic-select-query) you may be able to use the BuildSqlStatement() method of your query to see the generated SQL.

Comment: Yes BuildSqlStatement should do what he wants.

Answer (score 3):

Use SQL Profiler. It allows you to see the actual SQL query being sent to the database.

It comes with SQL 2005/2008 client tools.